# Are there any browsers that support HTML5's Canvas that don't default to an 'Accept-Encoding' of gzip?

Tags: http, canvas, browser, gzip

I'm creating a webapp where upon connecting to my server, you will have one simple HTML page downloaded with one Canvas element in said page. If your browser doesn't support Canvas, you'll get a message telling you to upgrade your browser in it's place. If Canvas works, then there'll be some interactivity between my server and the canvas element.

Since I'm writing my own server, I don't really feel like properly adhering to the W3C standards for dealing with `'Accept-Encoding'`, since writing a function to properly check which compression is ok is something I'd rather avoid (since there are a lot of other things I'd rather work on in my webapp). However, I feel like if a browser can support HTML5's canvas, then I can assume that it'll deal just fine with Gzipping, and I can have all the interactivity between the browser and my site be Gzipped without worrying about failure.

Does anybody know of any browsers that have HTML5 capabilities (specifically Canvas in my case) but take issue with Gzipped HTTP responses?

NOTE - I have had 0 experience with non-desktop browsers. My app isn't targeting mobile devices (resolution isn't large enough for what I'm working on), but I would be curious to know whether or not this holds for mobile browsers as well.

Best, and thanks for any responses in advance,
Sami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise against making any such assumptions.

The browser in question may support Canvas, but it could still sit behind a proxy which for some unknown reason does not support gzipped responses.

You could instead put your custom web server behind a proxy that is widely used, such as Apache or Squid, and let that proxy negotiate with the client for you. This way your own web server would only have to deal with a single client, which could simplify its implementation significantly. This intermediate proxy could also take care of many security issues for you so that you won't have to worry quite as much about hackers pwning your web server.

Comment: If a proxy for some odd reason doesn't support gzip responses but still receives a gzipped response, what would it do? would it not forward it onto the browser, and just drop the response?

Comment: That is up to the proxy, but if it sends a request to your server without any `Accept-Encoding: gzip` maybe it would ignore any `Content-Encoding` header and simply assume that your response is not gzipped. Perhaps that could result in the proxy gzipping the content again before it is passed down to the browser. The bottom line here is that you can not safely make any assumptions about the transport layer based on other features in the browser. You could of course decide to ignore the few clients who might experience problems with this and focus on getting results fast instead.

Answer (score 1):

Note that while I cannot think of any *browsers* with this limit, HTTP proxies might impose the limit. Since this is at the transport layer, you can't guarantee support for optional portions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article indicating the 10% of browsers did not support gzip as of 2009:  http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/11/11/whos-not-getting-gzip/

That being said, I would think any browser that has support for canvas would also support gzip (it is an easy piece of code to add).